# Duped Output in Powershell

Tags: python

Sometimes when I'm inputting for the below code, it will display two outputs instead of just one.  Also, it I choose a number too low, it will display "Pick a number between 1 through 10" instead of "that's a little too low, pick again!".

Something else I've noticed is I will start inputting from 1 all the way up to 10 but I will often times not get the message, "You guessed it, you won!"

I've attached the picture of my code, what am I doing wrong?  Is there something missing?

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPvJX.png)

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Ji8.png)

Comment: Please add your code in the question as text and not as an image. Otherwise search engines won't pick up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two outputs are displayed as you are using `print(input(`, which is unnecessary as replies to input statement will already show in the console. You are printing the input even though it's already there.

As for why you sometimes don't get the `You guessed it, you won!` message, it's because you don't change `guess` after a new guess it's entered.

Here's what that part of your code should look like:

```
while True:
    if guess < random_number:
        guess = input("That's a little too low, pick again!: \n")
    elif guess > random_number:
        guess = input("That's a little too high, pick again!: \n")
```

Also I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `if play_again == "y"`, that won't replay the game and in fact causes a `TypeError`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated!